# the_content() wordpress определенная часть

Tags: wordpress

Вывожу посты на странице с помощью цикла вордпресс.

```html
        <?php $args = array(
        'category_name=projects'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();?>

                <div class="mini-card">
                        <a class="mini-card__link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                            <div class="mini-card__img-cnt">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                <main class="mini-card__main">
                    <div class="mini-card__cnt">
                        <p class="mini-card__name"><?php the_title();?></p>
                        <p class="mini-card__description"><?php the_content()?></p>
                    </div>
                </main>
                </a>
                </div>


             <?php }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

На данным момент the_content() выводит весь контент поста, мне же надо выводить только текст, содержащийся в параграфе с классом `card__text` как можно это сделать, подскажите!

```html
<!--Контент поста-->
<p class="card__param">Общая площадь кровельных работ: 1900 м2</p>
<p class="card__param">Используемая гидроизоляция: ПВХ мембрана</p>
<p class="card__param">Экстраруф 1.2 мм</p>
<p class="card__param">Пирог: разуклонка керамзитобетоном, пароизоляция, минвата 160 кг/м3 Baswool, стяжка, 2 слоя Техноэласта</p>
<p class="card__param">Срок выполнения: май-июнь 2015 года</p>
<p class="card__text">Коттеджи на Дмитровском шоссе – это дома, где нет несущих конструкций, что позволит вам осуществить любые дизайнерские решения. А вековые деревья на вашем участке позволят создать уникальный ландшафтный дизайн. Обратите внимание, что этот дом дуплекс имеет самый большой прилегающий земельный участок в поселке - 14 соток! Если хотите купить коттедж, Дмитровское шоссе будет прекрасной альтернативой для проживания за городом в шикарном районе. Готовые дома в коттеджном поселке отвечают всем современным требованиям и потребностям будущих новоселов</p>
```

Comment: Если таких параграфов много, то лучше парсить с помощью simple HTML DOM. Если один и задан в точности таким html, как в примере, то выдернуть строковыми операциями.

Comment: Выводить ГДЕ? На архивных страницах (рубрики, метки, даты, и тд) или на самой странице поста?

Comment: Ок, я сейчас исправлю немного вопрос, чтобы было понятно

Comment: Если с html парсером - https://eval.in/916402

Comment: Правильный способ представления подобного контента - перенести параметры в произвольные поля. Не оч хороший - использовать фильтр на  the_content() и чистить регулярками. Несколько кривой, но менее затратный использовать поле "отрывок", куда продублировать нужный текст. А вместо  the_content() использовать the_expert()

Comment: @splash58 оформите ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать HTML parser. например, DomDocument

```
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />' .  the_content() );
$xpath = new domXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//p[@class="card__text"]') as $p) {
   echo $dom->saveHTML($p) ."\n";
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/916402)